# Should I implicitly declare the __constructor as public?

Tags: php

In a class that does not use a private constructor, the constructor is publicly available afaik. Consequently shouldn't every constructor be declared with the public prefix if one wants to be as clear as possible?

**Example**

```
<?php

class Y
{
    private $x;

    public function __construct($x)
    {
        $this->x= $x;
    }
}
```

**Instead of**

```
<?php

class Y
{
    private $x;

    function __construct($x)
    {
        $this->x= $x;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can you use class member declaration outside of the class?

Comment: Default visibility is public, so it's not explicitly required. Beyond that, it's opinion. I always include it for clarity, and I use a coding standard checker that requires it, to enforce consistency.

Comment: I always use: public function __construct($x)

Comment: @rahulsm Whoops, edited it, thanks for the note.

Comment: Be explicit.  No confusion

Comment: It;'s been a standard of coding style for a while, many people including me should always declare property/method visibility. PSR-2 http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to a hard and fast rule would be [PSR-2's recommendation](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#43-methods), which suggests that visibility should be explicitly declared on everything:

> Visibility MUST be declared on all methods.